# Overwriting method or hooking event in subclass?

Tags: c#, oop

Let say I have a product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public event ProductColorChangedEventHandler ColorChanged;
    protected virtual void OnColorChanged()
    {
        if (null != ColorChanged)
          ColorChanged();
    }
}
```

If I am inhering from this class and I need to catch the notification when there is a color change, is it better to override `OnColorChanged` or hook the event in my subclass constructor?

Comment: None of the above. The subclass should call `base.OnColorChanged()` and provide its own implementation on top of the base call. I see no reason to setup an event for this purpose.  Decorator pattern comes to mind.

Comment: Sorry I might have worded that incorrectly (i updated OP) It should say "catch the notification" not "get". In other words, I need to do something in my subclass when a color change event happens.

Comment: @BlueChameleon Then you mean "subscribe" to the event, or "add an event handler", not "catch" or "get".

Comment: In that case see `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the preferred method is to subscribe to the event in your subclass like this:

```
public class SubProduct : Product
{
  public SubProduct()
  {
      ColorChanged += new ProductColorChangedEventHandler(color_changed);
  }

  private color_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the method

```
public override OnColorChanged()
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, he *can*.  He's asking if he *should*, or if he should subscribe to the event.  Note that using your method, since you're not calling the base implementation, you're now failing to invoke all of the event handlers that subscribed to the actual event, which is why I dislike overriding the method like this.

Answer (score 0):

Hooking isn't the right way to do it when you are still designing your app.

Subscribe to the event in your subclass, is a clean solution to your problem.

Here is a good read: [Hooking on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#C.23_keyboard_event_hook)